# Find a closed form of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n^2+3n+2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form

The question I've been given is this:

Using both sides of this equation:
$$
\frac{x}{1-x} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n
$$

Find an expression for:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n^2+3n+2}
$$

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Decompose on partial fractions. The first formula is just true for $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** You may observe that

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}=-\ln (1-x), \quad |x|<1
> $$

(this may be proved by differentiating termwise the power series).

Then 
$$
\frac1{n^2+3n+2}=\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+2}
$$ gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^2+3n+2}=\frac1x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac1{x^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}, \quad 0<|x|<1.
$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

$$\frac{1}{n^2+3n+2}= \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}$$

Then proceed by integration.